# Clickevnts on MinorTickMarks getting minortickposition in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, axis

I want to get minortickmark value when i click on minortickmark in axis of barchart. I am getting all tickmark positions using getMinorTickPositions() in barchart. I have searched all js code in highcharts i am unable to find it.can anyone please help me. here is my code.

```
     $('.highcharts-axis').hover(function(event) {
    alert(this.x);
    getAxisValue();
    return false;
    }); 
    function getAxisValue(){
         var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
          var data= chart.xAxis[0].getMinorTickPositions();
         //alert(chart.value());
          alert(data);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In general to add click event to minor ticks will require some JS and Highcharts skills. I will try to guide you a little:

- `chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks` - this is where all minor ticks are stored
- to add click event to minorTick, use: `chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks['value'].mark.on('click', callback)`
- now in `callback` you can do your stuff for specific minor tick

Comment: Thanks for giving me hope to get solution. I am getting object while calling chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks[0]. how can i get value at 0. plese send me some sample code.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear for me what you want, also I won't write code for you, sorry..

Comment: I want to get minortickposition value when i click on minortick. Is it possible to get minortickposition value? I am getting allpositions using getMinorTickPositions(). But i want single value whwn i click on it.

Comment: Read once again my answer. I don't advice to use `getMinorTickPositions()` in my solution.. For example: `chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks[11]` means tick vlaue is 11. Returned object has properties like mark (which is SVG/VML element) and `pos` which is value also.

Comment: chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks[0] is giving object chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks[1] or otherthan minorTicks[0] giving undefined

Comment: Probably you have different minorTicks? First call `chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks;` to see what minor ticks are available, and then loop over them ( for example `for ( var tick in chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks ) { ... } ;`).

Comment: chart.xAxis[0].minorTicks its giving object how can i get data in that object